# Couldn't import Django when launching test server

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

When running the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

To launch a test server, I get the following error:

`ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

Steps I took to get this error:

1) I downloaded the Django project from my Linux VPS (without the virtual environment). I am using Windows 10 on this current system.

2) I created a new virtual environment in that folder using:

```
virtualenv myprojectenv
```

3) The env was created successfully, I now have the following folders/files:

`myproject
myprojectenv
static
manage.py`

4) I activate the env (`myprojectenv\scripts\activate`), success - my commandline changes to

`(myprojectenv) C:\ (path to my folder)`

5) I install Django using

`pip install django`

Django successfully installed, when checking the version, it returns 2.1.1:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())
2.1.1
```

6) I go back to the main dir where manage.py is, I try to run the test server with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And I get the error (specified above). So, what have I done wrong here? I have the env folder correctly in that directory, Django installed. It still can't find it.

I thought the problem may be with my Django files, but no. When I start a new project from the myprojectenv env using

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

The mysite folder gets created - I go into that folder (where manage.py is) and I try to launch the test server again. It still can't find Django! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What Python version does your virtual env uses?

Comment: I got it to work when I installed Django globally (to C:/Program Files). So seems like it was trying to use my system Django, not the virtualenv. How do I edit it so it uses virtualenv correctly?

Answer (score 2):

--- make all of them in order
virtualenv example

source example/bin/activate

cd example

pip install django

django-admin.py startproject mysite

cd mysite

python manage.py runserver

--It have to work 100%